# Is kernel 3.5.0.26 (64bit) intended for 12.10 or 12.04

Tags: 12.10, kernel, 64-bit, software-updater

software updater suggests 3.5.0-26 for my current installation Ubuntu 12.10

[image: Software updater screen print]

My system:

```
uname -a
Linux pfeiffep-HPE-580t 3.5.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 01:50:30 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What I've found on-line at [Package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=linux)

```
quantal (kernel): Generic complete Linux kernel. 
3.5.0.26.32 [security]: amd64 i386 
also provided by: type-handling
quantal-updates (kernel): Generic complete Linux kernel. 
3.5.0.26.32: amd64 i386
```

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and would greatly appreciate some advice on how to make sense of the discrepiencies.

Update - Now this is halting some upgrades from completion.

```
2013-03-26 14:02:14 remove libreoffice-emailmerge:all 1:4.0.2~rc1-0ubuntu1~quantal2 <none>
2013-03-26 14:02:14 status half-configured libreoffice-emailmerge:all 1:4.0.2~rc1-0ubuntu1~quantal2
2013-03-26 14:02:14 status half-installed libreoffice-emailmerge:all 1:4.0.2~rc1-0ubuntu1~quantal2
2013-03-26 14:02:14 status config-files libreoffice-emailmerge:all 1:4.0.2~rc1-0ubuntu1~quantal2
2013-03-26 14:02:14 status config-files libreoffice-emailmerge:all 1:4.0.2~rc1-0ubuntu1~quantal2
2013-03-26 14:02:14 status config-files libreoffice-emailmerge:all 1:4.0.2~rc1-0ubuntu1~quantal2
2013-03-26 14:02:15 status not-installed libreoffice-emailmerge:all <none>
```

Since I'm perfectly satisfied with kernel 3.5.0-24-generic I took a more assertive action

```
2013-03-26 14:20:39 startup packages purge
2013-03-26 14:20:39 status installed linux-image-generic:amd64 3.5.0.26.32
2013-03-26 14:20:39 remove linux-image-generic:amd64 3.5.0.26.32 <none>
2013-03-26 14:20:39 status half-configured linux-image-generic:amd64 3.5.0.26.32
2013-03-26 14:20:39 status half-installed linux-image-generic:amd64 3.5.0.26.32
2013-03-26 14:20:39 status config-files linux-image-generic:amd64 3.5.0.26.32
2013-03-26 14:20:39 status config-files linux-image-generic:amd64 3.5.0.26.32
2013-03-26 14:20:39 status config-files linux-image-generic:amd64 3.5.0.26.32
2013-03-26 14:20:40 status not-installed linux-image-generic:amd64 <none>
2013-03-26 14:20:40 status unpacked linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:40 remove linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42 <none>
2013-03-26 14:20:40 status half-installed linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status config-files linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:46 purge linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42 <none>
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status config-files linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status config-files linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status config-files linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status config-files linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status config-files linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status not-installed linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 <none>
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status half-configured linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:46 remove linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42 <none>
2013-03-26 14:20:46 status half-configured linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:47 status half-installed linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:51 status config-files linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:51 purge linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42 <none>
2013-03-26 14:20:51 status config-files linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:51 status config-files linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:51 status config-files linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:51 status config-files linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:51 status config-files linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 3.5.0-26.42
2013-03-26 14:20:51 status not-installed linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic:amd64 <none>
```

So I've refined my question somewhat - what are the implications of freezing my current installation at 3.5.0-24-generic?

Comment: That kernel will work well with 12.10; it's stable and tested and you should have confidence moving forward with it.  One of the good things about trying new kernels, though, is that if it should cause problems for any reason, you can easily boot back into the previous version to reverse any changes (choose to boot into Advanced Options from the Grub menu).

Comment: @Kelley Thank You, I am aware of the advanced options and have "locked" my system to the version stated due to instabilities in 3.5.0-25. I appreciate your suggestion, but I really want to understand the discrepiencies outlined in the question. I do plan to test thhis kernel AFTER fully understanding the implications and why the differences in info. I really don't have the confidence you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

The kernel should would just fine. I'm using it, with absolutely no problems.

```
$ uname -r
> 3.5.0-26-generic
```

Running 64bit installation of ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Thanks for your input ... are you running 32 or 64 bit; 12.04 or 12.10?.  The research seemingly indicates the is for 32 bit and for 12.04!

Comment: Updated question. 12.10 64bit.